# Strong Parameters and Find in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, strong-parameters

I am having trouble with strong parameters in my custom controller. I understand how to use strong parameters in a new or update action. However, I can't seem to figure out if this is an unsecure use of the params[]  hash or not in my custom action.

My view redirects to a controller with an order id and an operation number:

```
link_to 'Confirm', confirmpayment_confirm_path(order: order, operacion: order.operacion), :data => { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```

My confirmpayment controller is as follows:

```
class ConfirmpaymentController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def lookup
    authorize! :lookup, :confirmpayment
    @orders=Order.where(:status => 'PENDING')
  end

  def confirm
    authorize! :confirm, :confirmpayment
    @order=Order.find(params[:order])
    @order.payment_id = params[:operacion]
    @order.confirm_payment_date = DateTime.now()
    @order.save
  end

  def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:order, :operacion) 
  end

end
```

The question is:

I am not using `order_params` anywhere in my confirm action, since this is not a new order. I am using the parameter to find the proper order and confirm it. Is this secure? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Is the `payment_id` just an ID of an external provider or is it a foreign key that points to a record in the database. Eg. to a `Payments` table?

Comment: It's exactly that. A foreign_key that points to a record in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to clear a few things up.

Strong Parameters is responsible for the allowed parameters which are passed to your database. It should prevent the users to modify attributes in the database which they aren't allowed to modify.

**For example:**

You have the following table with columns:

```
User:
 - firstname
 - lastname
 - email
 - password_digest
 - role (user, admin)
```

You probably want to prevent normal users to change their `role`. But if you pass a parameters hash as it is to the database, he could also add a `role` key with value to the hash. Your application would accept it. **Strong parameters** checks the hash and prevent the change.

In your example above, Strong Parameters brings no advantages. You assign the values directly to the appropriate table columns. It isn't possible to modify any other attributes in the database for the user. If you don't have any other methods in your controller, you could remove the entire `#order_params`. Strong Parameters just raises an exception if you would try to pass a hash directly through.

However I would recommend you to search for the payment in the database before you assign it. If you assign `payment_id` directly you have no guarantee that payment exists. So first check for the payment and if you found it assign it to the order.

Here is how I would have done it:

```
class PaymentConfirmationController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :authorize_user!   # To DRY up your code

  def lookup
    @orders = Order.where(:status => 'PENDING')
  end

  def confirm
    @order = Order.find(params[:order_id])
    @payment = Payment.find(params[:operation_id])
    # You should catch the exceptions if an order or payment wasn't found

    @order.payment = @payment
    @order.payment_confirmation_date = Time.now()
    @order.save
  end

  private

  def authorize_user!
    authorize! :confirm, :confirmpayment
  end
end
```

I haven't tested the code but it should work.

Here are the [Docs of Strong Parameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html). They describe everything in more detail.

I hope this helps!

Happy coding :)

Comment: Finally got it! So strong parameters is there to protect from mass asignment when doing something like  `@order.update_attributes(params[:order])` into database directly. I will never feel comfortable with doing that even though it may be the Rails way. I much prefer to assign parameters directly as in the example.

Answer (score 1):

About the way of using parameter, I think there is nothing wrong with it. But about the security problem, you may want to think about the case that user can change any `Order` information by just change the `order` param to something that doesn't belong to him.

In that case, you will want to limit the query to `Order`, make he can only confirm the order that belongs to him.

Comment: Yeah sure. I am authorizing via cancan in this line: `authorize! :confirm, :confirmpayment` Only the order's owner or an admin can confirm it.

Answer (score 0):

**Strong Parameters**: prevent accidentally exposing that which shouldn't be exposed. They are generally used when you create or update a model, this to avoid entering parameters have not been allowed.

I have some suggestions:

1. English preferably encoding: `operacion` to `operation`
2. Check style
   in your code `ConfirmpaymentController` to class
   `ConfirmPaymentController`

you can see: [best practices and style prescriptions for Ruby on Rails 4](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide) :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions on styling. However the question remains: How would I use strong parametes in my custom controller? I have only seen examples for new or update actions.

Comment: your question was "Is this secure?", That is my answer.

Comment: @Augusto Basically it is the same behavior for the action that you need, only must consider the parameters you want to allow. My answer explains the use. _this to avoid entering parameters have not been allowed._